# Register a class in Autofac for InstancePerApiRequest and use in a background thread

Tags: autofac

I have a class that is Registered using InstancePerApiRequest, but I also need to access it outside of the scope of the request.  When the class is resolved in the background task I receive the following error: "No scope with a Tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest' is visible from the scope in which the instance was requested.".  Adding InstancePerLifetimeScope after InstancePerApiRequest corrects the error, but how does this effect the actual registration.  Am I still getting InstancePerApiRequest or did I just override the prior?

Note the task is created in a DelegatingHandler using .ContinueWith.

If this is not correct how can I accomplish this?

Comment: That doesn't make much sense.  Which instance do you want to get?

Comment: I want a new instance per request in most cases, except when the background task runs which is outside the request/response.  The background task should get an instance, but I get the AutofacWebRequest error instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to handle this I ended up registering them again using Named and AsInstancePerLifetime. So any background task resolves using the named lifetimes and items in the request/response flow use the ones registered with InstancePerApiRequest.